# Como configurar predicate para retornar somente 2 colunas?

Tags: query, objective-c, core-data

Cenário:

Fazer uma query usando CoreData procurando registros com uma cidade e estado, e retornar somente as colunas 'nome' e 'endereço' do local.

Atualmente estou usando seguinte query:

// Array que será retornado

```
NSMutableArray* arrayRegistrosFiltrados = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext * context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSError* error;

`// Instancia objeto que irá fazer a requisiçao
NSFetchRequest* requisicao = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:entidadeEstacionamento];
NSPredicate* argumentosBusca = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"estado==%@ AND cidade==%@",estado,cidade];

[requisicao setPredicate:argumentosBusca];

NSArray*registrosTemp = [context executeFetchRequest:requisicao error:&error];`
```

Mas deste modo retorna todos as colunas dos registros encontrados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe `NSFetchRequest` tem uma propriedade que se chama [propertiesToFetch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/propertiesToFetch).

Você pode usá-la da seguinte maneira:

```
...

[requisicao setPredicate:argumentosBusca];
[requisicao setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"nome", @"endereco", nil];

...
```