# Swift CoreDataModel Select

Tags: swift

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para selecionar apenas uma tabela especifica do meu CoreData, por exemplo eu tenho 6 campos, e gostaria de efetuar um select de apenas informações de um único campo, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Meu código atual:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "wordEasy = %@", "wordEasy")

do{
    let results  = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
    print(results)
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Baseado [nessa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91821/como-configurar-predicate-para-retornar-somente-2-colunas/92595#92595) porém em *Objective-C* você pode fazer:

```
//passe o(s) campo(s) que deseja dentro do Array 
request.propertiesToFetch = ["wordEasy", "wordMedium"]
```